# Quality Center 11 / QTP - Unable to view and amend xml resources

Tags: qtp, hp-quality-center

I'm using QC/QTP 11. I've creating an environment variable in QTP and exported/saved the file to QC so it is an external variable.  This is saved in the resource area of QC. However when I go to QC>Test Resources>Resource Viewer for the xml file I get the message "The asset viewer does not support this asset type". This does not make sense as one of the Asset Types is "Environment Variable". What I want to be able to do is amend the variable when required. The main purpose for this is to have a global variable for a url.  We have several test environments and need the ability to change this in one place to update all the tests we will run in the test lab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you can change this in one central location: The XML file.**

However, the multi-zillion-dollar software QC unfortunately is unable to display or even let you edit the XML from within QTP -- **you have to download it, edit the downloaded copy (with notepad, or whatever), and upload it again.**

In QTP, the change is visible for all tests opened after the upload.

If you are using version control, you must check-out, download, edit, save, upload, check-in the XML to make the change effective globally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did think of this approach but was hoping there might be a more elegant solution. I think we've decided to ignore QC altogether and save to a normal network location.

Comment: I'd say QC makes sense if your automation is part of a larger testing effort, and your automation team is larger than 1-3 persons.